# ZendX Console Process posix functions

Tags: zend-framework, zendx

I am catch the follow exception in my code:

ZendX_Console_Process_Exception' with message 'posix_* functions are required

What's posix function is need for it work right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am installed the php-process package.

In Red Hat, or Centos, to use:

```
sudo yum install php-process -y
```